# http checks python

Tags: python, http

learning python here, I want to check if anybody is running a web server on my local
network, using this code, but it gives me a lot of error in the concole.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import httplib
last = 1
while last <> 255:
        url = "10.1.1." + "last"
        connection = httplib.HTTPConnection("url", 80)
        connection.request("GET","/")
        response = connection.getresponse()
        print (response.status)
        last = last + 1
```

Comment: Gentlemen?  Not only, I think.

Comment: ask your question about each error specifically. And try googling the error before you ask your question.

Comment: If you're trying to get the status only, using HEAD instead of GET would be a lot better. I covered this in a similar solution that you should check out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140661/python-get-http-response-code-from-a-url/1140822#1140822

Comment: yes it's better to do as you say, Evan, but in this particular case it doesn't matter so much, because his real problem is that most of his requests won't be answered, so his approach won't be practical.  he needs to put in timeout for sockets, handle exceptions for timed-out connections, and add multithreading so that the timers aren't sequential. he also needs to check moreports than just 80 (e.g. 8000, 8001, and 8080).  in this context, what the load is that he retrieves from whatever few servers are there.  i'll try to post sample code shortly.

Answer (score 5):

I do suggest changing the while loop to the more idiomatic for loop, and handling exceptions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import httplib
import socket


for i in range(1, 256):
    try:
        url = "10.1.1.%d" % i
        connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(url, 80)
        connection.request("GET","/")
        response = connection.getresponse()
        print url + ":", response.status
    except socket.error:
        print url + ":", "error!"
```

To see how to add a timeout to this, so it doesn't take so long to check each server, see [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/ff84e7340988c168/).

Answer (score 2):

as pointed out, you have some basic
quotation issues.  but more fundamentally:

1. you're not using Pythonesque
   constructs to handle things but
   you're coding them as simple
   imperative code.  that's fine, of course, but below are examples of funner (and better) ways to express things
2. you need to explicitly set timeouts or it'll
   take forever
3. you need to multithread or it'll take forever
4. you need to handle various common exception types or your code will crash: connections will fail (including
   time out) under numerous conditions
   against real web servers
5. 10.1.1.* is only one possible set of "local" servers.  RFC 1918 spells out that
   the "local" ranges are   10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255, and
   192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255. the problem of
   generic detection of responders in
   your "local" network is a hard one
6. web servers (especially local
   ones) often run on other ports than
   80 (notably on 8000, 8001, or 8080)
7. the complexity of general
   web servers, dns, etc is such that
   you can get various timeout
   behaviors at different times (and affected by recent operations)

below, some sample code to get you started, that pretty much addresses all of
the above problems except (5), which i'll assume is (well) beyond
the scope of the question.

btw i'm printing the size of the returned web page, since it's a simple
"signature" of what the page is.  the sample IPs return various Yahoo
assets.

```
import urllib
import threading
import socket

def t_run(thread_list, chunks):
    t_count = len(thread_list)
    print "Running %s jobs in groups of %s threads" % (t_count, chunks)
    for x in range(t_count / chunks + 1):
        i = x * chunks
        i_c = min(i + chunks, t_count)
        c = len([t.start() for t in thread_list[i:i_c]])
        print "Started %s threads for jobs %s...%s" % (c, i, i_c - 1)
        c = len([t.join() for t in thread_list[i:i_c]])
        print "Finished %s threads for job index %s" % (c, i)

def url_scan(ip_base, timeout=5):
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
    def f(url):
        # print "-- Trying (%s)" % url
        try:
            # the print will only complete if there's a server there
            r = urllib.urlopen(url)
            if r:
                print "## (%s) got %s bytes" % (url, len(r.read()))
            else:
                print "## (%s) failed to connect" % url
        except IOError, msg:
            # these are just the common cases
            if str(msg)=="[Errno socket error] timed out":
                return
            if str(msg)=="[Errno socket error] (10061, 'Connection refused')":
                return
            print "## (%s) got error '%s'" % (url, msg)
            # you might want 8000 and 8001, too
            return [threading.Thread(target=f, 
                             args=("http://" + ip_base + str(x) + ":" + str(p),)) 
                    for x in range(255) for p in [80, 8080]]

# run them (increase chunk size depending on your memory)
# also, try different timeouts
t_run(url_scan("209.131.36."), 100)
t_run(url_scan("209.131.36.", 30), 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from the variable names `last` and `url`. Python is interpreting them as strings rather than variables. Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import httplib
last = 1
while last <> 255:
        url = "10.1.1.%d" % last
        connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(url, 80)
        connection.request("GET","/")
        response = connection.getresponse()
        print (response.status)
        last = last + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to connect to an url that is **literally** the string `'url'`: that's what the quotes you're using in

```
    connection = httplib.HTTPConnection("url", 80)
```

**mean**.  Once you remedy that (by removing those quotes) you'll be trying to connect to "10.1.1.last", given the quotes in the *previous* line. Set that line to

```
    url = "10.1.1." + str(last)
```

and it could work!-)