# How to get status code of remote url using Javascript/Ajax but NOT using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to check if a url is reachable or not using javascript without using jQuery or the method of loading an image from that url. It would be great if I can get the status code of that url, because all I care about is that status code being 200.

I have tried XMLHttpRequest but I learned that it does not support cross domain calls.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a server side script using a [server side language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Examples), have this script return the status code. This "proxy" script, will request the URL for you, so that no cross domain requests need to be made.

For an example of a Python response code script, see here: [What’s the best way to get an HTTP response code from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140661/python-get-http-response-code-from-a-url)

Hope that helps,
-Sunjay03

Comment: Thanks for your response, Sunjay The problem is that I do not have access to the server's code. It is external to me "literally". For example, the url could be anything (even http://www.google.com). The bottom line is that I don't have access to the server's code.

Comment: You do not need access to the server's code. My method of using a proxy allows you to avoid that entirely.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get the status code directly in JavaScript without XMLHttpRequest. As pointed out, this is generally only same-domain although, there are two possible cross-domain approaches (not requiring a proxy server) to this I know of:

1. Certain clients and servers willing to play can use [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and;
2. There are also [flash-based "XHR" solutions](http://code.google.com/p/crossxhr/wiki/CrossXhr).

On the other hand, if all that is cared about is the *image thought it could be loaded* (which might not be a 200 at all!) it is possible to find this out using an Image element and the `onload` event. If the `onload` event doesn't fire in a certain amount of time it can be concluded the request timed out or failed (4xx/5xx). However, this will return a false-positive in case of 302, etc.

Just make sure the browser actually tries to load the Image: some of the more clever ones won't load hidden images, or so I've heard.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about how "cross-browser" this is:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com" onerror="alert('error')"></script> <!-- Is Fine -->
<script src="http://www.notrealnotrealzz.com" onerror="alert('error')"></script> <!-- Alerts Error -->
```

And it's obviously a hack, but hopefully it will help.

A more dynamic version:

```
var el = document.createElement('script');
el.onerror = errorFunction;
el.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(el);
```