# Python URL redirection - Handle 302 which moves to 404

Tags: python, urllib2

I know we can handle redirection with `requests` and `urllib2` packages. I do not want to use `requests` as it is not a prebuilt package. Please help me with `urllib2` to handle a URL which takes a 302 and then moves to 404. I am not concerned about the 404 and I would like to track whether it is a 301 or 302.

I referred this [doc](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html) but it still throws the 404.

Here is my code

```
import urllib2
class My_HTTPRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        return urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)

my_opener = urllib2.build_opener(My_HTTPRedirectHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(my_opener)
response =urllib2.urlopen("MY URL")
print response.read()
```

Here is my response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in http_error_302
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 625, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Please, show some code you already wrote.

Comment: *"I am not concerned about the 404 and I would like to track whether it is a 301 or 302."* -- [the link that you provided](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html) already contains the solution: [`SmartRedirectHandler`](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html#oa.redirect.2.1), use `response.status` attribute to find out whether it  is 301 or 302 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use httplib and HTTP/1.1 `HEAD` method.  That way no response body is received.

[What’s the best way to get an HTTP response code from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140661/python-get-http-response-code-from-a-url/22123762#22123762)