# How to import python requests using a file in order to output the status code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-status-codes

I'm new with Python(3) so please don't bash me :D

I'm using the following code in order to import a .txt file which contains different URLs so I can check their status code.
In my example, I added 4 site URLs

here is the import.txt with just one URL:

```
https://site1.site
https://site2.site
https://site3.site
https://site4.site
https://site5.site
```

while this is the py script itself:

```
import requests
with open('import.txt', 'r') as f :
 for line in f :
  print(line)
#try :
 r = requests.get(line)
 print(r.status_code)
#except requests.ConnectionError :
#    print("failed to connect")
```

this is the response:

```
https://site1.site

https://site2.site

https://site3.site

https://site4.site

https://site5.site

400
```

Even though site3 and site4 are 301's while site5 has a failed to connect response I only receive a 400 response which applies to all of the submitted URLs.

If I request.head for each one of those URLs using the following script then I receive the correct page status code('Moved Permantly' for the example below). This is the single request script:

```
import requests
try:
    r = requests.head("http://site3.net/")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        print('Success!')
    elif r.status_code == 301:
        print('Moved Permanently')
    elif r.status_code == 404:
        print('Not Found')
#    print(r.status_code)
except requests.ConnectionError:
    print("failed to connect")
```

kudos to [What’s the best way to get an HTTP response code from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140661/what-s-the-best-way-to-get-an-http-response-code-from-a-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `requests.get()` is outside the `for` loop, and so is only executed once. Try indenting the relevant lines, like so:

```
import requests
with open('import;txt', 'r') as f :
 for line in f :
  print(line)
#try :
  r = requests.get(line)
  print(r.status_code)
#except requests.ConnectionError :
#    print("failed to connect")
```

Ps. I suggest you use 4-space indents. That way, errors like this are easier to spot.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, it worked :) I tried working with Python right away so you pointed a fact; I need to learn the basics first and space indents are definitely one of them.

Comment: I recommend you work through [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), from the official Python documentation.